# Where has the "define" ability gone when selecting a word in an SMS message or email?

Tags: iphone

When selecting a word in an SMS message or email, how do I access the "define" ability?

Comment: It's now called "Look Up"

Answer (score 1):

It's now labeled as "Look Up" in the menu.

[image: Selecting a word in IOS]